# Polymer <paper-checkbox> behaving erratically

Tags: polymer

I have completed the "Build an App" tutorial here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/toolbox/set-up and have noticed that the paper-checkbox element is not behaving well - it will intermittently freeze at various stages of the re-render. For example, when it is in the unchecked state, and I tap it, it will freeze with the grey circle surround, but without actually displaying the tick in the checkbox. It will also freeze in other states as well. 
I think the problem only occurs for screen gestures. I.e - it will fail on a mobile device for screen taps, and also on my Win10 laptop when I tap the (touch-sensitive) screen, but when I use the touchPAD on my laptop, it works reliably.

I am a raw beginner with Polymer. (and everything ;^)

Comment: I have used the element in my project, and have no such issue (https://jobijoy.com/) while signup.

Comment: HakanC - FWIW I've published the site to Firebase hosting, here: https://my-app-2aa06.firebaseapp.com It's the ES5 bundled build.

Comment: I tested ( Ready to deploy) its working good at my side. No freezing. (Samsung mobile)

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce the same symptoms with both Opera, and Samsung Internet browser.  Phone is a Samsung Note 5 on Android 7.0. Note also that quite frequently, nothing at all happens when I tap, and I have to tap again to make something happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to a known issue ([`PolymerElements/paper-checkbox` Issue #156](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-checkbox/issues/156)).

I can reproduce the buggy ripple animation on your site in Chrome 66 on macOS High Sierra when emulating mobile mode. It seems to intermittently occur after switching views (e.g., to *View Three* and then to *New View*) and then clicking the checkbox **label** (clicking the checkbox itself does not exhibit the problem).

Part of the problem is the checkbox's ripple has a "focus" state, where it shows the middle of the animation (the "frozen grey circle" you mention) when the checkbox gains focus. I'm not sure that's by design.

I recommend voting on the GitHub issue, or creating a new issue if you think it's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks - that does indeed look related - amazing if it's the same problem, some 18 months later! Is Polymer a dead-end product?

Comment: I don't think it's a dead-end product. As far as I know, the team is currently focused on the upcoming Polymer 3 release, so maybe that's taking their attention away from GitHub issues.